# Presets for radio buttons with jQuery

Tags: jquery, select, radio-button

how can I set presets for radio buttons with jQuery?

Here is a simple example: http://jsfiddle.net/EpQgr/

```
<select>
   <option>option 1</option>
   <option>option 2</option>
</select>

<div>
    <input id="radio1_0_0" type="radio" name="radio1" value="1" />x
    <input id="radio1_0_1" type="radio" name="radio1" value="2" />y
    <input id="radio1_0_2" type="radio" name="radio1" value="3" />z
</div>
<div>
    <input id="radio2_0_0" type="radio" name="radio2" value="1" />x
    <input id="radio2_0_1" type="radio" name="radio2" value="2" />y
    <input id="radio2_0_2" type="radio" name="radio2" value="3" />z
</div>
```

The pre set options should be something like this:

```
//option 1
$("#radio1_0_1, #radio2_0_2").prop("checked",true);

//option 2
$("div input:first-child").prop("checked",true);
```

Comment: Your fiddle works. What is your question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change your html code in this way:

```
<select>
   <option value="">Choose a preset</option>    
   <option value="#radio1_0_1, #radio2_0_2">option 1</option>
   <option value="#radio1_0_0, #radio2_0_0">option 2</option>
</select>
```

and the JS

```
$('select').on('change', function() {
    var v = $(this).val();
    if ($(v).length) {
        $(v).prop("checked", true);
    }
});
```

The elements to check are stored inside `value` attribute of each option.
This solution avoids having to enter each preset inside the handler of the select. If you need to insert a new preset just add the option with a new selector
 
see jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/8f7Nw/2/

Answer (score 0):

You probably want the dropdow to be used to select the radio options

try this:

```
$("select").bind("change", function() {

    // un select all
    $("input[type=radio]").prop("checked",false);

    if($(this).val() === "option 1") {
        //option 1
        $("#radio1_0_1, #radio2_0_2").prop("checked",true);
    }

    if($(this).val() === "option 2") {
        //option 2
        $("div input:first-child").prop("checked",true);        
    }
});
```

Your [fiddle updated](http://jsfiddle.net/EpQgr/2/)